# phone pe payment gateway sdk integration react native

Tags: react-native, phonepepaymentsdk

What data will be send to make transaction in phone pe PG for example : body, checkSum,      packageName, appSchema
how to make transaction...!

```
/**
    * This method is used to initiate PhonePe B2B PG Flow.
    * Provide all the information as requested by the method signature.
    * Params:
    * - body : The request body for the transaction as per the developer docs.
    * Make sure the request body is base64encoded
    * - checkSum: checksum for the particular transaction as per the developer docs.
    * - packageName: @Optional(for iOS) in case of android if intent url is expected for specific app.
    * - appSchema: Your custom URL Schemes, as per the developer docs.
    * Return: Will be returning a dictionary / hashMap
    * {
    * status: String, // string value to provide the status of the transaction
    * // possible values: SUCCESS, FAILURE, INTERRUPTED
    * error: String // if any error occurs
    * }
    */
startTransaction(
body: string,
checkSum: string,
packageName: string | null,
appSchema: string | null
):Promise;
```

Example:

```
PhonePePaymentSDK.startTransaction(body, checkSum, packageName, appSchema).then( a => { console.log(a) })
```

I am trying to make transaction using phone pe pg sdk but i don't understand how to do this

startTransaction(
body: string,
checkSum: string,
packageName: string | null,
appSchema: string | null
):Promise;

Example:

```
PhonePePaymentSDK.startTransaction(body, checkSum, packageName, appSchema).then( a => { console.log(a) })
```

what data will be send in : body, checkSum, packageName, appSchema

Answer (score 0):

The PhonePePayment SDK has a GitHub repository with examples on how to do this.

I can recommend you check it out [here](https://github.com/PhonePe/pg-sdk-react-native-sample/blob/main/pages/Home.tsx#L15).

```
const handleStartTransaction = () => {
      PhonePePaymentSDK.startTransaction(
        requestBody,
        checksum,
        packageName,
        callbackURL
      ).then(a => {
        setMessage(JSON.stringify(a));
      }).catch(error => {
        setMessage("error:" + error.message);
      })
  };
```

Also, their [developer documentation](https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/reactnative-sdk-integration/) has information regarding the arguments for the method you requested.

Comment: problem is with checksum and body

Comment: @JasimKhan - You can check out the checksum here -> https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/android-pg-sdk-integration.  Both the checksum and the body are things defined in your server.